# Probability based on random variables!

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, random

I am stuck with the following math question and I am not sure the best way to approach it. As of now I have listen out all of the potential combinations have multiplied those by 5. I assume there is a smarter way to do this!

The question is such as: A professor is preparing an exam with five questions. Each question must yield a point ranging between 1-4. 1 point being the minimum and 4 being the maximum. The sum of all of the five questions must be 14. In how many ways can she subdivided the points for all of the five questions?

Comment: [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is useful here.

Comment: Thank you lulu, I will take a look at it and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: lulu, how would I integrate the sum using the Stars and Bars example. I can figure out the total amount of combinations, but how do I figure out how many of the combinations gives 14?

Comment: Actually, I hadn't noted the maximum.  That makes the problem simpler.  I'll post something below.

Comment: Look at the enumeration I provide below.  I strongly suggest checking it carefully.  It is conceptually straight forward, but it's easy to skip a case or botch a computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work off the maximum of $4$.  Specifically, we'll start by counting $4's$.  We note that we can't have more than three.

Case I. $3\;4's$.  Then the other two add to $2$, so the pattern is $\{4,4,4,1,1\}$.  There are $\binom 53$ ways to place the $4's$ so $\fbox {10}$

Case II.  $2\; 4's$.  Now the other three must add to $6$.  The patterns are $\{4,4,3,2,1\},\{4,4,2,2,2\}$ and we get $\binom 52\times 6=\fbox {60}$ and $\binom 52\times 1= \fbox {10}$

Case III. $1\; 4$.  Now the other four must add to $10$.  the patterns are $\{4,3,3,3,1\},\{4,3,3,2,2\}$ and we get $\binom 53\times 2=\fbox {20}$ and $\binom 52\times \binom 32 =\fbox {30}$

Case IV.  $0\;4's$.  As $3\times 5=15$ we can only have the pattern $\{3,3,3,3,2\}$ so $\fbox 5$.

In the end we get $$10+60+10+20+30+5=\fbox {135}$$

Note:  While this kind of enumeration isn't really difficult, it is certainly prone to error so I advise checking.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd think it is easier to simply use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) with [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Firstly we can put the minimum $1$ mark in each question,
and now we can fill non-negative integers totalling $14-5=9$

To take care of the upper limit, we put $4$ in one or more question(s) to make such solutions "bad", and apply inclusion-exclusion

Thus $\binom{13}4 - \binom51\binom94 + \binom52\binom54 = 135$